# Deriving uncertainty relation between operators (Zettili)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, notation

Zettili's Quantum Mechanics, section 2.4.5 (p95):

$\hat A$ is an operator and $\langle\hat A\rangle$ is its expectation value with respect to a normalized state vector. Then the operator $\Delta \hat A$ is defined: $$\Delta\hat A = \hat A - \langle\hat A\rangle. \tag{1}$$

What confuses me is that $\hat A$ is a matrix and $\langle\hat A\rangle$ is a (complex) number. So what is the result of subtracting a number from a matrix?

Comment: @Qmechanic's answer is perfect. I would like to add just that you will see such unimportant abbreviations everywhere in physics. Don't let them intimidate you.

Comment: @Andreas Mastronikolis: Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implicitly written identity operator
$$\Delta\hat A ~:=~ \hat A - \langle\hat A\rangle\hat{\bf 1}$$
in the definition (1).